# Troubles with multilanguage (variations)

Tags: variations, multilingual, replication

I am in troubles with multilanguage and I hope some of you can help me.

I have a Microsoft SharePoint 2010 site in two languages: spanish (default) and portuguese, I have done a redesign of a lot of pages (normal pages and design pages) in the spanish site. The problem is the modified pages aren't copying to portuguese: If I go to see the site in portuguese I only see the pages with the old design (before being modified).

I have other problem I think cause of above: the box where the user can change the language isn't shown.

Anyone has any idea about that? You can askme any new information.

Thankyou.

Comment: What kind of redesign you made? Changed content? Worked with SharePoint designer? Other?

Comment: The type of redesign is through SharePoint Designer over the design pages and throught internet navigator over the normal pages, but that is not the point. The point is the changes I have done aren't replicating to Portuguese.

Answer (score 2):

While SharePoint does provide certain multilingual features, we find that our clients require a little more flexibility and responsiveness in the multilingual user interface and content delivery as well as a simplified method to manage multilingual content and documents. PointFire provides this solution as well as providing many other useful tools for customizing the look and behavior of your SharePoint sites.

SharePoint variations require the creation of separate sites and the automatic provisioning of alternate variations of your content, which need to be translated and then maintained by a trained staff on the use of those variations. [PointFire](http://www.icefire.ca) enables your users to work on one site in multiple languages and store your documents/items in the same lists but giving you the power to filter that content based on language. Using variations requires only a rudimentary understanding of SharePoint lists and libraries, whereas SharePoint variations requires much more advanced training.

Users can easily manage multilingual HTML elements, text and images using the PoitnFire SDK, which is essentially server tags that allow you to indicate a segment of HTML code is meant for a specific language. PointFire will filter those HTML segments based on language on the fly. It is a very simple solution and requires very little effort to implement.

Answer (score 0):

When you use SP Variations in the "publishing" page tab there are other buttons like "Update". One of your language is the master. So, you have to create the new content or design in the master lenguage, then "update" for other language.

I have a diferent problem. When i change the language from Spanish or English to Portuguese, the "top navigation" disappear!!!, Any help please!!!!!

Regards!